How to resolve Tailwind CSS warning about missing or empty content option in configuration?
I am currently developing a project using Tailwind CSS with Vite, and I am encountering the following warning message during development:
warn - The content option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
Steps Taken:
I ensured that the tailwind.config.js file exists in my project.
I restarted the Vite server after making changes to the configuration.
I cleared the cache in Brave browser to ensure old styles are not being used.
Despite these steps, the warning persists, and the Tailwind CSS styles do not apply correctly in my application.
Any help would be appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Check your content configuration is relevant for your project.

I have the same problem after updating Quasar (using new Webpack, changed app to type: module). I don't know why.

Ok, my problem was that I was starting the app not from root folder using quasar dev, so tailwind could not find config file in that directory.

Make sure your tailwind.config.js has a content property.
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  // ...
}

This property tells Tailwind which files in your project it should scan for the existence of classes.
Tailwind only generates CSS for classes that you're actually using in your project (if it included the CSS for every class, the CSS file would be massive).
Since you didn't define content, Tailwind isn't scanning any files, and therefore isn't aware of the classes you're using. Your application is missing styling because Tailwind didn't generate the underlying CSS for those classes.
See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration for configuring content
